# Is app.use(route, express.static(folder)) safe from directory traversal attacks?

Tags: node.js

Ex:

```js
app.use('/', express.static(public));
```

Does that also ensure requests made to `/` will only be able to access contents in `public/` folder? Or should I implement further protection?

Comment: Thats the neat part, you can try it by your self. + You can take a look at the source code.

Comment: @Marc Just because one didn't manage to exploit a feature it doesn't mean the feature is exploit-safe. There are multiple ways to try path traversing, if I managed to it definitely means it's unsafe, but if I don't manage to it doesn't mean it's safe. That's why I'm asking it on stack

Comment: And just because some on answer does not mean its save either. There is no 100% safety.

Comment: @Marc one answer managing to exploit it (in a way I don't manage to) is enough to disproof it's exploit-free

Comment: I guess that something you have to weigh up. How critical is this issue for you? And perhaps there a better options to solve your "problem" e.g. Isolate your app in a container or Jail.

Comment: @Marc there are a lot of implications for directory transversal attacks. One may bypass the site authorization by accessing some file that should only be accessible for specific users. I agree isolating the app is good for a lot of reasons, but for that concern preventing the DTA would avoid many beyond problems